# Check if coordinates intersect rotated rectangle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, coordinates, intersect, validation

In a non-GIS system, I have a Python script that checks to see if coordinates are valid:

```
def is_latlong_valid(laty, longx):
    #Verify if the numbers are legitimate UTM coordinates
    return (4856762 <= laty <= 4879371 and
            663546 <= longx <= 677126)
```

The script checks if the coordinates are within a certain un-rotated rectangle (grey text, black box).

- I suppose this could be considered a sort of *minimum bounding envelope*.

[image]

In reality, the geographic area I want to check the coordinates against is  a **rotated** rectangle (black text, blue box).

Is there a way to enhance the script so that it checks the rotated rectangle, instead of just the un-rotated rectangle?

- I do not have access to any spatial libraries.
- I don't even have access to most of the standard Python libraries, and I am unable to import additional libraries.

---

Related questions:

Stack Overflow: [Determine if points are within a rotated rectangle (standard Python 2.7 library only)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63527698/10936066)

Code Review: [Determine if points are within a rotated rectangle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248297/determine-if-points-are-within-a-rotated-rectangle/248449#248449)

Comment: In your situation classic approach seems most suitable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: You're asking for a Python solution, but you state that the JavaScript API is available.  Do you really mean the ArcGIS API for Python?  The math for PIP calculation of a 5-vertex polygon is not beyond the capabilities of even an indifferent Python programmer (and are present in the cited SO post).

Comment: @Vince Wups, I can see how that was misleading. I actually did mean JavaScript. It's the wild west over in the IBM Maximo world. We write Python scripts and pass values over to JavaScript functions in a pinch. And work in a bit of Java too. But that's just confusing, so I removed the part about JavaScript from the question. And no, unfortunately, we don't have the ArcGIS Python API in Maximo. We only have the ArcGIS JavaScript API.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ArcGIS API for Python you can create a [Geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html#geometry) (or Polygon) object based on your rectangle, and then create a [geometry filter](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.filters.html) based on this Polygon. Your lat/long coordinates sound like a series of points, so you could create a [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) of points based on these coordinates. This probably requires creating a layer in ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. Then you can run a spatial [query](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.query) on the Feature Layer identifying which points fall within the rectangle. To run a spatial (vs non-spatial) query use the "geometry_filter" parameter of query(), as is described in the reference documentation linked above for geometry filters.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ArcGIS API for Python is not available.

Comment: Ah, I see the clarification above about which API. Haven't worked with the Javascript API, but doing a quick search of it's documentation suggests that it can do spatial queries and create geometries, so you should be able to apply the same logic with Javascript API. Here's a page on spatial queries in the Javascript API: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html

Comment: @ycartwhelen Thanks. I'm quite interested in using the Javascript API. I've got some reading to do!

Answer (score 0):

From a related Code Review post: [Determine if points are within a rotated rectangle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248297/determine-if-points-are-within-a-rotated-rectangle/248449#248449)

```
def dot_prod_with_shared_start(start, end1, end2):

    return (end1[0] - start[0]) * (end2[0] - start[0]) + (end1[1] - start[1]) * (end2[1] - start[1])

def is_inside_rectangle(vertices, point):

    return all(dot_prod_with_shared_start(vertices[i - 1], v, point) > 0 for i, v in enumerate(vertices))

rect_vertices = [(670273, 4879507), (677241, 4859302), (670388, 4856938), (663420, 4877144)]
test_point = (663783.170, 4877029.787)

print(is_inside_rectangle(rect_vertices, test_point))
```